# Асинхронный ввод и вывод данных

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть сервер на Qt/c++, он слушает определенный порт и принимает с него данные. Когда к нему поступают какие-нибудь данные, они выводятся на консоль. Однако параллельно с этим мне бы хотелось в консоли осуществлять управление сервером. Т.е. необходимо принимать команды. 
Я выделяю отдельный поток на чтение команд и в нем работает такая функция:

```
std::string readCommand()
{
    std::string command;
    getline(std::cin, command);
    return command;
}
```

Но при этом сервер перестает принимать данные и отвечать на них. Как можно распараллелить это?

Сервер запускается, работает без ГУИ (в терминале). В качестве клиента использую telnet.

OS: Mac OS X High Sierra
Qt 5.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сокеты работают асинхронно, через очередь событий.

Как работает эта очередь:

1. Внутри функции `QCoreApplication::exec()`, которую вы в обязательном порядке вызываете из `main()`, крутится вечный цикл.
2. На каждой итерации этого цикла производится проверка *системной очереди сообщений*, в которую операционная система заботливо складывает все уведомления приложению от системы, драйверов и других программ. Данные, полученные сокетом, также посылаются в виде уведомлений.
3. Если очередь непуста, из неё извлекается очередное сообщение.
4. На основании данных в сообщении определяется `QObject`-получатель, в метод `QObject::event()` которого необходимо передать данное сообщение.
5. Реализация `QObject::event()` конкретного объекта может делать всё что угодно. `QTcpSocket`, к примеру, пишет новоприбывшую порцию данных во внутренний буфер и испускает сигнал `readyRead`.
6. После возврата управления из `QObject::event()` возвращаемся в п. 3.
7. Если же очередь пуста, засыпаем до прихода сообщения, затем возвращаемся в п. 3.

Как видите, для получения данных из сокета надо хотя бы иногда возвращать управление в обработчик очереди событий. Иными словами, возвращаться из функций, которые вы непосредственно не вызывали.

Вы же блокируете выполнение программы вызовом `std::getline()`. То есть пока пользователь не введёт в консоль строку, сервер и его очередь сообщений будут простаивать.

Теперь **решение** проблемы. Есть два способа: один *как правильно* и один *чтоб просто работало*:

- первый способ — убрать консоль из сервера и заменить её на [именованный канал](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365780(v=vs.85).aspx), к которому можно будет подключаться любым из уже существующих терминальных клиентов (тем же Putty). Избавление от интерфейса пользователя позволит отвязать сервер от пользователя и запускать его как службу, как любую нормальную взрослую программу-сервер.
- второй способ *(если вас не устроил первый — напишите в комментариях почему)* — разнести сокет и блокирующее чтение из консоли по разным потокам. Переносить при этом стоит именно сокет (вызвав для этого `QTcpSocket::moveToThread()` перед `connectToHost()`), так как весь UI привязан к главному потоку.

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ, обязательно воспользуюсь первым способом (честно говоря, в голове и так крутился переход к нему, но было желание попробовать потоки, а с ними не срослось, потому и задал вопрос).